# @KafkaListener with multiples independent topics processing

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

Software used:

- Java version: **8**
- SpringBoot version: **2.4.0**
- SpringKafka version: **2.7.2**

I have this method in my spring:

```
    @KafkaListener(topics="#{consumerSpring.topics}", groupId="#{consumerSpring.consumerId}", concurrency="#{consumerSpring.recommendedConcurrency}")
    public void listenKafkbooiaTopic(@Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_TOPIC) String topicName, @Payload String message, Acknowledgment ack) throws Exception {
        ConsumerSpring consumer = this.consumerSpring();
        //
        //
        KafkaHandlerReturn handlerReturn = consumer.getKafkaProxy().handleRequest(
                topicName,
                consumer.getConsumerId(),
                message);
        
        if (handlerReturn.equals(KafkaHandlerReturn.SUCCESS) || handlerReturn.equals(KafkaHandlerReturn.FAIL_LOGIC)) {
            ack.acknowledge();
        } else {
            ack.nack(5 * 1000);
        }
    }
```

`#{consumerSpring.topics}` returns

```
{"topic1", "topic2", "topic3"}
```

`#{consumerSpring.consumerId}` returns:

```
myConsumer
```

`#{consumerSpring.recommendedConcurrency}` returns:

```
3
```

OK! This is working fine! But I need isolate these topics, for example:

TopicA is stuck in fatal error and it's calling:

```
ack.nack(5 * 1000);
```

But the topics: TopicB and TopicC aren't stuck. Then I need that these topics continue the execution normally.

Basically I need the same behavior as if I declared two separate structures, example:

```
    @KafkaListener(topics="topica", groupId="#{consumerSpring.consumerId}")
    public void listenerTopicB(@Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_TOPIC) String topicName, @Payload String message, Acknowledgment ack) throws Exception {
        ConsumerSpring consumer = this.consumerSpring();
        //
        //
        KafkaHandlerReturn handlerReturn = consumer.getKafkaProxy().handleRequest(
                topicName,
                consumer.getConsumerId(),
                message);
        
        if (handlerReturn.equals(KafkaHandlerReturn.SUCCESS) || handlerReturn.equals(KafkaHandlerReturn.FAIL_LOGIC)) {
            ack.acknowledge();
        } else {
            ack.nack(5 * 1000);
        }
    }
    
    @KafkaListener(topics="topicb", groupId="#{consumerSpring.consumerId}")
    public void listenerTopicA(@Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_TOPIC) String topicName, @Payload String message, Acknowledgment ack) throws Exception {
        ConsumerSpring consumer = this.consumerSpring();
        //
        //
        KafkaHandlerReturn handlerReturn = consumer.getKafkaProxy().handleRequest(
                topicName,
                consumer.getConsumerId(),
                message);
        
        if (handlerReturn.equals(KafkaHandlerReturn.SUCCESS) || handlerReturn.equals(KafkaHandlerReturn.FAIL_LOGIC)) {
            ack.acknowledge();
        } else {
            ack.nack(5 * 1000);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I feel like separate methods is the solution here since you're being blocked by the method body's usage of `ack`. Or you could ack on a background thread, but that might cause other issues

Comment: There is no need for multiple methods.

You can put multiple `@KafkaListener` annotations on a single method and each one will create a separate container.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for multiple methods.

You can put multiple `@KafkaListener` annotations on a single method and each one will create a separate container.